# how to recover BCACHE from EC2 machine reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reboot, recover, bcache

I installed BCACHE on a m3.large EC2 machine with instance SSD as cache disk and the elastic volume as backing disk.  But once I reboot the EC2  machine BCACHE was gone and i cannot access the disk used to be backing drive again.

If I detach SSD(run BCACHE without cache) before reboot then after reboot v will still be there and i can attach SSD to it again.

The question is how do I recover BCACHE from a EC2  unclean reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to unregister your cache devices on shutdown/reboot and re-create and attach them on boot, if not, It will cause you pain every time you decide to shut down your instance. There is a script that automates the startup and shutdown in the first

For the unclean case (forced stop or sudden instance crash) you need to

`echo 1 > /sys/block/[Backing Device (EBS)]/bcache/running`

Example:
`echo 1 > /sys/block/xvdf/bcache/running`

Or if you use writeback and you assume your backing device will always boot healthy you can just add that line into your boot sequence (before your volume is mounted)

References:

- [My guide on using bcache with ec2](http://blog.rralcala.com/2014/08/using-bcache-in-ec2.html)
- [Bcache Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/bcache.txt)

Comment: thanks. but from the past experience, the bcache directory doesn't exit after unclean reboot.

Comment: I was talking about /sys/block/xvdX/bcache/running (the ebs block device itself), after doing that your bcache directory will appear.

Comment: I tried a unclean reboot again and I was able to register the cache disk on /sys/fs/bcache/register again and recover bcache. The directory you mention /sys/block/bcaching Device/bcache/running is not there. Thanks anyway.